# Is there any way to get all components of a Folder using TcmID of the Folder?

Tags: core-service

I am trying to get all the components inside a folder using tcmId is there any way ?

Comment: Hi Sneh, it would help us, help you if you can include some context. Do you need details from the components or just to know what's in there? Do you need to extract that data or do something with it? What technology are you expecting (Powershell, C#). Also what did you try already - there are examples even in TREX not just the www.

Comment: Hi Dylan ... I am trying to get all the component info inside a folder. If you're having tcmUri of a Folder then can you get the info of all the components inside a folder. Only info for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean with an API call? Using CoreService? If yes, GetListItems is your friend. Examples:

- [Filtering the result of GetListItems()](https://docs.rws.com/792149/677322/sdl-tridion-sites-9/filtering-the-result-of-------------getlistitems--)
- [How to list the existing Components of a Folder using WebDAV URL in Tridion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9597208/how-to-list-the-existing-components-of-a-folder-using-webdav-url-in-tridion)

Comment: Thanks Nuno...  that helps !!